# Is there a way to specify a dependency where anyone of a group can satisfy the demand?

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

Let's say I'm packaging an RPM which requires **one** of the following,

```
Foo
Bar
Baz
```

Does RPM support the functionality to put that into a spec file?

Comment: Examples spec file : `Requires: /usr/bin/gs` or `Requires: perl(CGI)` ... If the any installed or available package provides /usr/bin/gs, then "Requires" is fulfilled.

Comment: Yea, but what if you need `/usr/bin/sed` or `/usr/bin/perl`, but you need one of the two?

Comment: Starting with rpm 4.13.0, rpm supports boolean expressions in all dependencies. For example: `Requires: (pkgA or (pkgB and pkgC))` https://rpm.org/user_doc/more_dependencies.html

Answer (score 1):

I am going to convert Larsen comment into an answer:

Starting with rpm 4.13.0, rpm supports boolean expressions in all dependencies. https://rpm.org/user_doc/more_dependencies.html

For example:

```
Requires: (pkgA or (pkgB and pkgC))
```

In your case that would be:

```
Requires: Foo or Bar or Baz
```

Availability in rpm-4.13+ means that it is available in RHEL 8 and all recent Fedoras.

If you want this in RHEL 7 then you can workaround it using virtual provides. You can specify:

```
Requires: some-server-capability
```

and then in packages Foo, Bar, Baz you have to put there:

```
Provides: some-server-capability
```

This, unfortunately, requires modification of packages Foo, Bar, and Baz. If they are not under your control and you are on RHEL 7 or older, then you are doomed.

Note that some packages already use this virtual provides. E.g., you can:

```
Requires: smtp-server
Requires: webserver
```

And e.g., webserver is provided by httpd, nginx, or lightttpd packages.